# React.js: How do I set up a good Workflow that goes beyond a To-Do list with multiple Views

Tags: web-applications, workflow, reactjs

Last week I read about `React.js` and got really excited about it, but I can't find any good tutorials wich help me with the basics like:

- how to set it all up with Node.js
- and still go beyond a simple one-class To-Do-List.

Normally I would make Web-Apps with some HTML/PHP-Files, Javascript and AJAX, but I have no Idea how to build a `React.js app` with multiple Pages/Views and what the proper File-Structure could be - I guess it's not js, css and html ;)

Had anyone, somehow the same issues as me or do you know some great tutorials which could help me with that. I'm feeling kind of lost

Comment: Check out https://github.com/enaqx/awesome-react for a list of resources on React, and https://github.com/mikechau/react-primer-draft for a general guide to React.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

personally I like the flow of Django (framework), Django Rest Framework (for api) and React as my view.   This is what's great about react, it gets out of the way of those first two choices and just handles the view.   So in your case it could be Django, Node, MVC.NET, or Rails.

Getting your setup right is going to be specific to your back end tech, and not React itself.

With Django in particular, you need to have a running site, database tables defined and a restful API that can deliver that data in JSON (preferably).

Once you have this API setup, this should be able handle authentication, authorization etc..., because React won't help you with that.  This can be a major headache to setup, which is why I choose a tried and true framework like Django and Django Rest Framework since all of the authentication, authorization and throttling are built in for me, I just need to configure it.

Your framework of choice will handle routing urls although there are React add-on's to help with this.

Basically no matter what back-end tech you use to setup your stack, React will make rendering your UI awesome, but it doesn't involve itself in the hardest part, which will be setting up a stack that does everything I just mentioned, communicates with the database, authentication, authorization, throttling, validation etc... etc...